# Problem with number theory textbook exercise

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am reading Richard Mollin's textbook 'Fundamental Number Theory With Applications' and I am having trouble figuring out problem 1.50 in the following sequence of problems:

1.48. Prove that if a and b are relatively prime and c is an integer such that c | (a + b), then gcd(a, c) = 1 = gcd(b, c).

1.49. Prove that if a, b, c ∈ Z with a | c, b | c, and gcd(a, b) = 1, then ab | c .

1.50. Let a and b be relatively prime integers and let c be any natural number. Prove that there are inﬁnitely many natural numbers of the form a + bn with n N such that gcd(c, a + bn ) = 1. ( Hint: Use both Exercises 1.48– 1.49. )

How do I prove this?

EDIT:
So far I've tried to prove this for the special case where c is a power of a prime. I was unable to do so, and I'm not even sure if this is the right direction to go.
Here's my work so far:

Suppose

c = $p^n$

where p is a prime.
Note that c is coprime with everything except multiples of p.

Case 1: p | a and p | b

This case cannot arise because a and b are not relatively prime here.

Case 2: p | a but p does not divide b

In this case, we can get infinitely many numbers of the desired form such that their gcd with c is 1 by taking a + b(p') where p' is a prime that is not equal to c

Case 3: p | b but p does not divide a

In this case, any number of the form a+bn is coprime with c because p does not divide it.

Case 4: p divides neither a nor b

I was unable to prove the desired property in this case.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: For case 4: if $p\not\mid a$ and so $\gcd(a,c) = 1$, then for any integer $k$, $\gcd(a+bkc, c) = \gcd(a,c) = 1$. Choose $n$ as any multiple of $c$.

Comment: So would this work as a proof for 1.50 if I replaced 'p' with 'c' throughout?

Comment: @Chair My line above still works without requiring $c = p^n$, only that $\gcd(a,c) = 1$. By the same property, if there is one $n_0$ (which may be $0$) that satisfy $\gcd(a+bn_0, c) = 1$, then there are infinite such $n$, because $\gcd(a+b(n_0+kc), c)=1$. What left to be proven is that even if $\gcd(a,c)>1$, there are still at least one such $n$.

Comment: Okay, I forgot that c$\nmid$a does not imply that gcd(a,c)=1. So how can this be proved for the general case?